# Why is this C array giving the "Expected Expression" error?

Tags: arrays, c, variable-length-array

learning the C programming language and reading the documentation with Xcode 13.2 open and a Command-Line Tool project in front of me.
Reading this, in the Declarations/Arrays/Variable Length Arrays section:

```
{
   int n = 1;
label:
   int a[n]; // re-allocated 10 times, each with a different size
   printf("The array has %zu elements\n", sizeof a / sizeof *a);
   if (n++ < 10) goto label; // leaving the scope of a VLA ends its lifetime
}
```

And copying it in Xcode, inside the `main` function, it just gives me the "Expected expression" error next to the `int a[n];` line. I tried to put this into a separate function but this was not the solution.
What is going wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: variable size arrays is a non standard c feature any only supported by some compilers

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say "Expected **constant** expression"?

Comment: Once a variable is declared, you can't simply declare it again.

Comment: And *why on Earth* would you use a `goto` for this?

Comment: @NotationMaster Try your code at www.ideone.com

Comment: @pm100 so does Xcode not support this?

Comment: @WeatherVane 100% sure

Comment: @NotationMaster It does.  But that's not your problem.

Comment: @TrippKinetics no idea why there is a `goto`, I copied the documentation and pasted it here to try to understand it.

Comment: Have you explored the macro `__STDC_NO_VLA__`?

Comment: also you cant put a label on a declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that can follow a label is a *statement*, and a declaration is not a statement.  You'll have to wrap the code following the label in a block somehow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int n = 1;
label:
   do {
    int a[n];

    printf( "The array has %zu elements\n", sizeof a / sizeof a[0] );
    if ( ++n < 10 ) goto label;
  } while ( 0 );

  return 0;
}
```

Now the results should be what you expect:

```
$ ./vla
The array has 1 elements
The array has 2 elements
The array has 3 elements
The array has 4 elements
The array has 5 elements
The array has 6 elements
The array has 7 elements
The array has 8 elements
The array has 9 elements
```

For the love of God don't do this.

**EDIT**

Using just an empty statement after the label:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int n = 1;
label:
  ;
  int a[n];

  printf( "The array has %zu elements\n", sizeof a / sizeof a[0] );
  if ( ++n < 10 ) goto label;    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or just use `;` the empty statement.

Comment: @o11c: Or that, yeah - working on another issue for `$DAYJOB` and not spending a lot of cycles on this

Comment: @o11c what is the `;` empty statement and how would I use it in this case?

Comment: @NotationMaster: just put a `;` on a line between the label and the array declaration - C99 and later support mixed declarations and code.  You just need a statement (which includes an empty statement) after the label to make it work.

Comment: @JohnBode thank you, I will never do this conscientiously, I am just studying :-)

Comment: @NotationMaster personally I tend to put the semicolon on the same line, but yeah, that. Also note that, even though MSVC (the worst C compiler still in use) doesn't support all of C99, "mixed declarations and code" is one of the parts it does support, so there is no reason to put all the declarations up front like ancient compilers required. (MSVC also does not support VLAs, but VLAs should be avoided even on compilers that do support them).

Comment: I am a very beginning, not even a programmer yet, just passionate about it and learning it using the tools I have and hoping they do what is necessary. Is by any change that MSVC == Xcode returns true? :)

Comment: As far as the *compiler itself* is concerned, XCode >>>>> MSVC (XCode should support the most recent language standard, MSVC does not).  As far as the other IDE features are concerned (editor, project manager, debugger, etc.), I have no opinion.  I don't use either in may day-to-day work.